# ajax call calling an mvc async method never returns

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

i have an ajax call in my view chtml calling an async method in my controller. The problem is that the result is never returned even though the controller method does do a return. So in the browser it keeps waiting for the response and the ajax success or complete method are never called. It works if i do it synchronously. I am using mvc 4, .net 4.5.

In my view i have the following ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '@Url.Action("PopulateCertificatesViewModel")',
   data: data,
   success: function(certificatesViewModel) {
     alert('success');
     //do stuff with the response data...

   },
  complete: function() {
    alert('complete');
});
```

In my controller i have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> PopulateCertificatesViewModel(int orderId)
{
   var service = getservice();

   await Task.Run(() =>
            {                    
                response = service.getData();
            });

   return Json(response);
}
```

Comment: Do you have `targetFramework` set to 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My request would return from the controller and would just be in a pending status in the browser with the content from the request never showing up. I had made sure I was using MVC 4 and .NET 4.5 and had the `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` set in my web.config.

In the end what fixed it for me was using IISExpress instead of the Cassini web server that comes with Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks Joel, whoever you are! What a smart guy, you are the next jon skeets!

Comment: I have the similar problem but the restriction is that i cannot upgrade my project to target 4.5, it needs to target .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

try $.ajax with `contentType :'application/json'`. I should work.

Comment: Use $( document ).ajaxError(function( event, request, settings ) {} ); and try to trap the error. It would help to to find out the actual issue.

Comment: did u try keeping a brake point on controller async request!!

Comment: Yes it exits the controller method, but the Ajax doesn't receive the response. It works fine when done synchronously.